# Group By With VBA

Tags: vba, excel, grouping, excel-2013

I have a worksheet that has a header row, and I want to group the rows using VBA.  I have attempted this syntax

```
Sub GroupItTogether()
  Dim rLastCell As Range
  Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1),  _   
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
  Range("A2" & rLastCell).Select
  Selection.Rows.Group
  ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
End Sub
```

However, this will produce an error of:

> Invalid or unqualified reference

Highlighting the line of code: `After:=.Cells(1, 1)`

What must I do to group all rows (sans the header) with VBA?

**EDIT**

Per comments, I edited my syntax to the below, which removes the error but this does not group all rows (excluding header).  How should this be updated to group by the used range?

```
  Sub GroupItTogether()
  Dim rLastCell As Range
  Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), _    
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
  Range("A2" & rLastCell).Select
  Selection.Rows.Group
  ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: what if you remove dot before `.Cells(1,1)`?

Comment: That will randomly group two rows, not group from row 2 to the last used range.

Comment: You did wrong with `.Cells(1,1)`. You can use `.Cells(1,1)` when you wrote `With` before this. Check: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm

Comment: @bzimor - removing the "." will allow it to compile but it is still not grouping as it should.  See edit.

Comment: Do you want last used row by finding "*"?

Comment: Problem is `Find` returns number and `Range("A2" & rLastCell)` may be `A285` if `rLastCel=85`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Select` and `Selection`. Once you find the Range for `rLastCell` , you can read the last row property from your range with  `rLastCell.Row`, and then just group them.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GroupItTogether()

Dim rLastCell As Range

Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

Range("A2:A" & rLastCell.Row).Rows.Group
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1

End Sub
```

**Note**: you can get the last row that has data in Column A with :

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

(no need to use the `.Find` method)